# Web Service error 'Could not create type' when calling service from Ajax

Tags: ajax, web-services, asp.net-2.0

I've downloaded the Ajax Control toolkit

When I create a website from the Ajax control Toolkit template, I can create a web service in a single file (asmx) and hook this up to different Ajax controls provided in the toolkit.

However if I add the Toolkit to an existing ASP.Net 2.0 appliction web project I cannot create web services in a single asmx file. If I create a web service VS always creates a code behind file as well. As a result of this calls to the web service (or loading the service directly in the browser) generate the following error:

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'AddAjaxToApplication.List'.
Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="List.asmx.cs" Class="AddAjaxToApplication.List" %>
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I fixed this in the end.

In VS 2005 I just needed to right click on the web service and select "View Markup". I just changed the markup to use the correct namespace:

```
Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="List.asmx.cs" Class="List" %>
```

I Just removed the project name from the namespace to match the namespace used by List.asmx and this error went away.

Comment: You'd think Visual Studio would do this automatically ... if you didn't already know better.

Comment: Besides that remark - the classname is case-sensitive (as usual)

Comment: Thank you - VS 2013 still has this problem!

Comment: Mine was the opposite. It needed the full [Namespace].[Project].[Class] name. But your idea was the seed :)

Comment: Also don't forget namespaces are case sensitive. (FML.)

Answer (score 1):

In my instance I had renamed the class something different than the .asmx file, so when referencing the file from the .aspx code it would generate this error.

So I had 'AjaxManager.asmx', but had renamed the class to 'AjaxService', and the markup did not match. In my case, leaving the fully qualified namespace did not cause any issue. So if you change the class name (probably not reccomended anyway), make sure to correct the markup as well as shown below:

```
<%@ WebService Language="vb" CodeBehind="AJAXManager.asmx.vb" Class="MyProject.UI.AjaxService" %>
```

Comment: I did the same mistake. I had expected Resharper to take care of renaming but of course I should have thought more.

Answer (score 1):

One more Important Things and simple solution that i found out while creating web service . **Try to avoid creating code behind file**

I was facing same problem while accessing web service in  a virtual directory in iis 7 , then i created inline code asmx file and then access it , it was accessible

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by moving the code behind file `MyService.asmx.cs` to the `App_Code` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by ensuring that `MyService.dll` was deployed in the `/bin` folder below my `Web.config`.

Answer (score 1):

Check in the Published folder if the path for the specified class files really exist or not, For me the App_Code folder was not present in the published directory so I manually placed the folder there and it is working perfectly :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by giving the full path of the codebehind like this

CodeBehind="~/codebehind.asmx.cs"